# Custom tag or utility method which is better to use display value on JSP

Tags: java, jsp, custom-tags

I want to show the date on the view layer based on different formats.

I am obtaining custom formats such as `MMM YYYY, Yr, H/Yr etc.` as another attribute from the same object.

In this case, Which is best option. I have two options

1. Write a custom tag and invoke before showing on the screen
2. Write a utility method and call from the JSP page.

Is there any other way?

Which is the best approach?

Comment: Is [`formatDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) not sufficient?

Comment: no, beacuse the format values I am obtaining as qyr, hyr, YYYY like that

Comment: How about formatting dates before rendering page.